# Can you attach conditions to ARM template outputs?

Tags: azure

I am trying to output a Public IP address from a template only if it is a STATIC one however it doesn't seem to work.

Currently the below output should only output an IP address if the parameter PIPAllocation method is 'Static". However I keep getting the error "Unable to evaluate template output'publicIpAddress' is not valid.

Are you able to use conditions or IF statements in outputs for Arm templates?

```
"outputs": {
"publicIpAddress": {
  "value": "[if(equals(parameters('PIPAllocationMethod'),'Static'), reference(variables('primaryPIPAddressName')).ipAddress, parameters('PIPAllocationMethod'))]",
  "type": "string"
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that using the `if()` function ([example](https://gist.github.com/krnese/59f3f2668ecd9b02402bf31bbc6bf253)).

the only caveat is that both sides of the if are evaluated, so both expressions must be valid

Comment: can you send me an example of trying to output the ip address if the parameter PIPAllocationMethod is static ? as the lines i have posted dont seem to work, If the  PIPAllocationMethod s id dymanic it should ignore the line but i still get errors. If it is static i still also get errors

Comment: well, thats another question, you should accept this answer and raise a new question

Comment: but the original question hasn't been answered as the code i put up doesn't work! Hence the reason for the question to get a working piece of code

Comment: well, the original question is: "Are you able to use conditions or IF statements in outputs for Arm templates?"

Comment: ok i posted another question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48226376/how-can-i-output-a-public-ip-address-from-an-arm-template-only-if-the-allocation

Comment: you should probably accept this answer, as it answers your original question

Comment: You should accept this as the answer to the question you originally asked. This is the correct answer