# How can i output a Public IP address from an Arm template only if the allocation method is static?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I am trying to output a Public IP address from an arm template only if the PublicIP being create dis static. If it is Dynamic the output can be ignored.

We have a main template which calls another template to create the virtual machine. The calling template will pass the parameters required to build the machine including whether the Public IP should be static or dynamic using the parameter PIPAllocationMethod.

In the template which builds a vm in the output section I have tried the following code but it doesnt work and returns error as below "Unable to evaluate template output'publicIpAddress' is not valid."

```
"outputs": {
"publicIpAddress": {
  "value": "[if(equals(parameters('PIPAllocationMethod'),'Static'), reference(variables('primaryPIPAddressName')).ipAddress, parameters('PIPAllocationMethod'))]",
  "type": "string"
}
```

What I need is to only output the PublicIP Address if is is Static, if it is Dynamic it can be ignored

Help appreciated

Comment: is that a public ip or nic ip?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are talking about PublicIP resource, so you have a typo (case sensitivity):

```
reference(variables('primaryPIPAddressName')).IpAddress
```

for NIC use this:

```
reference(variables('primaryPIPAddressName')).ipConfigurations[0].properties.privateIPAddress
```

in your case i suggest you do this. créate variable with the following value:

```
"picker": "[if(equals(parameters('PIPAllocationMethod'),'Static'), 'IpAddress', 'publicIPAllocationMethod')]"
```

and in your output you can do this:

```
"value": "[reference(variables('primaryPIPAddressName')).[variables('picker')]]"
```

Comment: I tried that but still get {
14:13:24 - [ERROR]             "code": "DeploymentOutputEvaluationFailed",
14:13:24 - [ERROR]             "target": "publicIpAddress",
14:13:24 - [ERROR]             "message": "The template output 'publicIpAddress' is not valid: 
14:13:24 - [ERROR] The language expression property 'IpAddress' doesn't exist, available 
14:13:24 - [ERROR] properties are 'provisioningState, resourceGuid, publicIPAddressVersion, 
14:13:24 - [ERROR] publicIPAllocationMethod, idleTimeoutInMinutes, dnsSettings'.."

Comment: can you advise how I can fix it? if I call the template with the value  "static" in the parameter (publicIPAllocationMethod) then I only want to output the value if the IP is static and ignore the output if the parameter (publicIPAllocationMethod) is dynamic. Are you able to help ?

Comment: you mean the "picker" variable answer?

Comment: I added the line : "value": "[reference(variables('primaryPIPAddressName')).[variables('picker')]]" but there is a red line under the variables (howvering over it it says excpected the end of a string). also where are you getting the variable primaryPIPAddressname from? I'm passing a parameter into the template not a variable...thanks for your patience

Comment: i copy pasted that variable from your question. the other thing is just a bug in intellisense, you can also try using it without `.`

Comment: thanks but I got an error from the output window as follows  : 5:02:31 - 3:02:30 PM - Resource Microsoft.Resources/deployments 'IPTMgmtServer' failed with message '{
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidTemplate",
    "message": "Deployment template validation failed: 'The template output 'publicIpAddress' at line '334' and column '25' is not valid: Unable to parse language expression 'reference(parameters('publicIPAllocationMethod')).[variables('picker')]': expected token 'Identifier' and actual 'LeftSquareBracket'.. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template-expressions for usage details.'."
  }

Comment: try without the dot, also you are missing another `]` at the end

Comment: getting more but different errors now  ...will look again on Monday and update...thanks again

Comment: Did some more testing and worked perfectly! Thank you for the help

Comment: hey mate, did this work for you? care to accept\upvote? :)